# Unit Test in Python with If Else conditon

Tags: python, unit-testing

Suppose we have the following function:

```
import unittest
def func_test():
    indicator = True
    if(indicator == True):
        a = 5
        b = 10
        total = a+b
        return total
    else:
        a = 6
        b = 10
        total = a*b
        return total


class TestJob(unittest.TestCase)
    
    total = func_test(indicator = True)
    def test_func_test(self):
        self.assertGreater(total, 0)
```

How would we test the `else` condition for the unit test?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but if you pass `False` to `func_test` doesn't that fall in to your else?

Comment: You need `func_test(indicator = True)` instead.

Comment: With the given code, since `indicator` is set at the top of your method, it cannot and will never be `False` so you cannot test the else branch

Comment: You can't -- not as written, anyway. You can only test code paths that are reachable. Your code is basically `if(true) return`, so anything after that can never get executed.

Comment: @butterflyknife: Would you have to change the return statement to something else?

Comment: You can't simply pass `indicator = True` as a keyword argument if `func_test` itself isn't defined to accept such an argument, which involves changing the parameter list and getting rid of the hard-coded assignment `indicator = True` in the body of the function.

Comment: Your code before the edit was testable by simply changing the keyword argument to `False`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original version of the question was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `indicator` a parameter of the func_test.

```py
def func_test(indicator=True):
    if indicator:
        ...
    else:
        ...


class TestJob(unittest.TestCase)
    
    def test_func_test(self):
        self.assertGreater(func_test(indicator=True), 0)

    def test_func_test_else(self):
        self.assertGreater(func_test(indicator=False), 0)
```